# Interpreting variables but ignoring escape sequences in PHP HEREDOC

Tags: php, escaping, heredoc, nowdoc

I am trying to figure out how I can use HEREDOC syntax to interpret variables but ignore the backslash character. Or use NOWDOC syntax to allow for the interpretation of variables. An example of what I am trying to do:

```
$title = "My title here";
$date = "Aug 12, 2017";

$latex_code = <<<LCODE
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \pagestyle{head}
    \firstpageheader{
        $title
        $date
     }
LCODE;

file_put_contents("article.tex", $latex_code);
```

I want to ignore all slashes but interpret the variables $title and $date. Is there a way to do this without exiting from a HEREDOC or NOWDOC block?

Comment: Can you escape it? What do you mean by "ignore" the backslash, actually? Just interpret it literally, or not include it at all?

Comment: I'm not sure 2 vars inside curly brackets will be translated. Suggest wrapping vars you want translated with their own pair of curly brackets..   \firstpageheader
        {$title}
        {$date}
     
LCODE;

Comment: @Don'tPanic I am trying to export this all to a text file exactly as is, but with variables interpreted. I have updated my question to indicate this with the file_put_contents line.

Comment: @DuaneLortie There seems to be no issue with the braces.

Comment: What output are you getting? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of misunderstanding the intended output, I think you could just escape the backslashes. (I'm assuming you want the single backslashes included in the output.)

```
$title = "My title here";
$date = "Aug 12, 2017";

$latex_code = <<<LCODE
    \\documentclass{article}

    \\usepackage{graphicx}

    \\pagestyle{head}
    \\firstpageheader{
        $title
        $date
     }
LCODE;
```

Obviously if you don't do that, some of them (e.g. `\f`) will be [escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) that will be interpreted.